# In c# wpf, can I build listview column dynamically to a class method?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, dynamic

I'm going to display the list of data using listview, the data class contain the following elements:

```
class MyData
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }

    private LED[] LEDs = new LED[21];
    private byte[] servos = new byte[21];
}
```

And it is expected to display the data in table format as below,

```
{selected} {id} {name} {servo[1]} {servo[2]} ......
```

(servo[0] should be hidden)

with the layout of each column:

```
- {selected] : checkbox
- {id} : right alignment
- {name] : left alignment
- {servo} : right alignment, with background based on LED setting
```

I have build the ListView as below

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvData" FontSize="13" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>            
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding selected}" Checked="Selection_Changed" Unchecked="Selection_Changed" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="id" Width="60">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>

                <GridViewColumn Header="s01" Width="35">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="{Binding Path=LED01}" Margin="-5,0,-5,0">
                                <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Path=S01}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="s02" Width="35">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="{Binding Path=LED02}" Margin="-5,0,-5,0">
                                <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Path=S01}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                :
                {repeat for s03...s20}
                :

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

With some properties added to my data class:

```
        public string LED01 { get { return GetLED(1); } }
        public string S01 { get { return GetServo(1); } }

        public string LED02 { get { return GetLED(2); } }
        public string S02 { get { return GetServo(2); } }
```

And two methods GetLED & GetServo return the color & display based on the value of array LEDs & servos with given index.

It seems really dummy that I have repeated the GridViewColumn block many times, and 40 dummy properties have been created as it cannot bind to the method directly.

May I know if there has any simple way to build the listview?

In fact, the size of array is not fix, 21 is just the maximum size.

I'd like to know if it can build the column dynamically, so that it can be created based on the actual size, and those repeated columns can be done within a loop.  And set the Background & Data content based on class method, so that I can set to GetLED(?) & GetServo(?) directly without building a dummy property for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Size of LEDs and Servos will always be same, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's going to build a class for them, so it will become an array of servo class with LED.  But in existing program they are in two array.

Comment: ok. I am thinking on the solution for this. I thought of an approach but need some time to tell you.

Comment: Is it feasible for you if LED and Servo columns are empty for some rows? e.g.: for id = 1 there are 10 LED and Servos,  But for id=2 there 15. Then in ListView , 5 columns will show empty for row where id = 1.

Comment: There has other global setting defined the number of servo being used, and it will be used from 1 to n.  Within this n servo, if there has no value for display, the function GetServo(i) will return empty string.  So, you may assume that all of them must have value.  In fact, it's not display the value directly, GetServo has some transformation on the value, for example, value > 240 will show "---" instead of the integer value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that, both GetLED & GetServo will return string, and LED is enum type, where GetLED will return the color based on the value, and GetServo will return the display content based on servos value, these two method are not return the array content directly.  So, it must use these method for setting color and display content.

Comment: I suppose easiest way might be to build those columns in code, not in xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is little bit lengthy and logical. I tried to achieve the functionality you need.

Kindly go throw following:

**MODELS**

I divided LED and Servo detail to a different class and took List object of that class into MyData class.

```
class MyData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public List<MySubData> lstSubData { get; set; }
}

class MySubData
{
    public string LED;
    public string Servo;
}
```

**Converters**

We need two converters during this process.

In ColorConverter, you need to define your condition for generating different colors based on LED value.

```
public class TextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToString(value).Split('#').First();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
    var val = System.Convert.ToString(value).Split('#').Last();

        //YOUR COLOR CONDITIONS HERE. I AM RETURNING SIMPLE ONE COLOR

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWPF" Height="300" Width="400" 
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lvData" FontSize="13" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Margin="0,0,0,0" >

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CodeBehind**

The main logic I applied is in code behind (C#). I generate ListView.View in CS page only.
This code will generate dynamic GridView and DataTable for both UI and data.

I took sample data to simulate your requirement. You can take actual data. I took a variable globalServo for defining setting (as you mentioned in comments) for number of columns.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public int globalServo = 21;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<MyData> lstMyData = new List<MyData>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            List<MySubData> lstMySubData = new List<MySubData>();

            for (int j = 0; j < globalServo; j++)
            {
                lstMySubData.Add(new MySubData() { LED = "LED" + j, Servo = "Servo" + j });
            }

            lstMyData.Add(new MyData()
            {
                id = i,
                name = "name-" + i,
                selected = Convert.ToBoolean(i % 2),
                lstSubData = lstMySubData
            });
        }

        lvData.View = GenerateGridView();
        lvData.ItemsSource = GenerateSource(lstMyData).DefaultView;
    }

    private GridView GenerateGridView()
    {
        GridView view = new GridView();

        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Id", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Id") });
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Name", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name") });
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Selected", CellTemplate = GetCheckboxTemplate() });

        for (int i = 1; i <= globalServo; i++)
        {
            view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Servo" + i, CellTemplate = GetTextBlockTemplate(i) });
        }

        return view;
    }

    private DataTable GenerateSource(List<MyData> dataList)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Selected");

        for (int i = 1; i <= globalServo; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Servo" + i);
        }

        foreach (var item in dataList)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = item.id;
            row["Name"] = item.name;
            row["Selected"] = item.selected;

            for (int i = 1; i <= globalServo; i++)
            {
                row["Servo" + i] = item.lstSubData[i - 1].Servo + "##" + item.lstSubData[i - 1].LED;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dt;
    }

    private DataTemplate GetCheckboxTemplate()
    {
        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(CheckBox));
        FrameworkElementFactory chkElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        dt.VisualTree = chkElement;

        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Selected");
        chkElement.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, bind);

        return dt;
    }

    private DataTemplate GetTextBlockTemplate(int Index)
    {
        TextConverter textConverter = new TextConverter();
        ColorConverter colorConverter = new ColorConverter();

        DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextBlock));
        FrameworkElementFactory txtElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        dt.VisualTree = txtElement;

        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Servo" + Index);
        bind.Converter = textConverter;
        txtElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);

        Binding bind1 = new Binding();
        bind1.Path = new PropertyPath("Servo" + Index);
        bind1.Converter = colorConverter;
        txtElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, bind1);

        return dt;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**NOTES**

This is a very basic sample which simulate the scenario you mentioned in your question with all mock data. I took every class, converters in single page only. You need to take care of object references / namespaces while managing proper folder structure for your project. I tested this code and this is working as attached image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to understand the details.  and update the status after testing.

Comment: @JamesMA Please go through it and also I added "NOTES". Let me know. In nutshell, I moved everything to code behind.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the sample, it seems work in my case.
I've try to study the code, as I haven't try building listview from code before, I'd like to clarify some logic here.
It seems that a data table has been created with dynamic columns containing the value of GetLED and GetServo value separated by "##".
Moving to my case, the content of element in lstSubData becomes GetServo(i)  + "##" + GetLED(i).
And the converters (TextConverter & ColorConverter) will work on those dynamic columns to extract the Text and Color from it.

Comment: In this case, it may need to rebuild the DataTable whenever the data is updated.  Isn't it?
Does it mean that the listview cannot link to a method directly, so it has to create the element with the final value?
BTW, may I know how to set the textalignment in code?  I can't find such property in FrameworkElementFactory.

Comment: Yes. You have to rebuild DataTable each time. I think , there is not other way in your case.

Comment: Thanks  a lot, and i find that the text alignment can be set by SetValue method.

Comment: Yes. You can set many properties using SetValue. Cheers :). Put comments here if need more help.

Comment: It seems that the ItemContainerStyle in XML has no effect in this case.  The original one will fill the whole cell with LED color.  But now, only the text has background color.    Need to study how to build everything back from code.  :P

Comment: you can define ItemContainerStyle  for all ListViews in app.xaml file. Normally we use "Strech" for all listviews. Else you need to apply from code behind

Comment: All thing which you do in XAML (UI), can be done from code behind (C#) with more control over the code and more customization.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to learn how to build from code.  But it seems that the structure of GridViewColumn cannot be  mapped directly from XAML.

Comment: I have try adding the style in app.xaml under Application.Resources, but there has no effect also, maybe something is wrong.

        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>

Comment: After testing, there has some problem in the example:
1) A data table has been created for dipslay, so the action on checkbox will not update the original data.
   The event handler of checkbox cannot tell which row is checked, it has problem to update back to original data.  It may need to check the status of all records even only one checkbox is updated.
   
2) The cell not highlighted, still can find how to bind grid background for datatemplate.  I guess there may have such setting, but still not found.

Comment: Hi @JamesMA This is very basic sample I shared with you. You can explore and use properties of `Binding`. 1) Bind `Tag` of checkbox to your `Id` and also you can register events for checkbox. In those events you can get `Tag` value in `Sender` object and using id , can perform other operation. 2) You can change datatable and gridview as both the object are accessible in code behind. updating datatable will update the UI as well. All you need to do it to reassign the source.  I am not saying it is very easy but once your start exploring this, you will understand and gain.

Comment: I have modified the sample, and add some logic for my case, it can display as expected now, but I still cannot solve the problem to identify the row when checkbox is changed.  I'll try to see if I can link the tag to the Id, or I have to make the row as selected (I found some example link the row selection to checkbox, so SelectedIndex can refer to the checked row).  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JamesMA have you ever found a solution on how to cange source data when target is updated?